# Возникает ошибка при работе с потоками

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, шаблоны-с++, ссылки

При попытке скомпилировать код возникает следующая ошибка:

> In file included from main.cpp:1:
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread: В конкретизации «std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [с _Callable = void (&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string&, std::mutex&); _Args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >&, std::reference_wrapper}; <параметр-шаблона-1-3> = void]»:
>   main.cpp:27:44:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:120:44: ошибка: неудача static assertion: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
>     120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
>         |                                            ^~~~~
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread: В конкретизации «struct std::thread::_Invoker, std::allocator >&, std::mutex&), std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::reference_wrapper > >»:
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:131:22:   требуемый из «std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [с _Callable = void (&)(std::__cxx11::basic_string&, std::mutex&); _Args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >&, std::reference_wrapper}; <параметр-шаблона-1-3> = void]»
>   main.cpp:27:44:   required from here
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:243:4: ошибка: нет имени типа «type» в «struct std::thread::_Invoker, std::allocator >&, std::mutex&), std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::reference_wrapper > >::__result, std::allocator >&, std::mutex&), std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::reference_wrapper > >»
>     243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
>         |    ^~~~~~~~~
>   /usr/include/c++/9.2.0/thread:247:2: ошибка: нет имени типа «type» в «struct std::thread::_Invoker, std::allocator >&, std::mutex&), std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::reference_wrapper > >::__result, std::allocator >&, std::mutex&), std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >, std::reference_wrapper > >»
>     247 |  operator()()
>         |  ^~~~~~~~

Полистав интернет я так и не смог понять в чём ошибка. Скорей всего я не там искал.Подскажите, как исправить или где посмотреть.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>

void add(std::string& str, std::mutex &m) {
        m.lock();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            str += ((char) (random() % 10));
        }
        m.unlock();
}

int main() {
    std::string happy = "HelloHappyWorldCat";
    std::mutex m;

    std::thread th1(add, happy, std::ref(m)); //1 поток

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас содержимое вопроса принципиально меняется на лету??? Тут так не разрешается. Я откатил все изменения. Если на ваш вопрос ответили - отмечайте ответ и задавайте другой вопрос (или *дополняйте* исходный). Никаких переписываний содержимого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, ну, понятно, можно просто добавить `ref`, как вы сделали с `m` (вы же передаете *ссылки*... непонятно, кстати, чем вы руководствовались, добавляя `ref` только к одному из двух аргументов):

```
std::thread th1(add, std::ref(happy), std::ref(m)); //1 поток
```

Только вот плохое это решение - передавать ссылки на локальный объект, который при выходе из функции прикажет долго жить...

В вашем случае программа завершится раньше, чем запустится поток (да и то не факт), так что поток может при везении и не успеть обратиться к какой-то некорректной памяти - только вот всегда ли так будет?
Передавать что-то в поток по ссылке можно, только если вы в состоянии гарантировать, что объект, на который указывает ссылка, будет существовать все время работы этого потока...